# Javascript beginner

Tags: rgb

I'm trying to make it so that the rgb values entered change the background colour. I have already written the html part.

**html:**

```
Red Value<input name="red" type="text">
Green Value<input name="green" type="text">
Blue Value<input name="blue" type="text">
<input name="submit" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="changeBackground();
```

For the `javascript` I know it would start with

```
function changeBackground(){
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (see code comments for explanation):

```
function changeBackground() {
    // get values of all input boxes
    // getElementsByTagName returns array, you need just first element
    var red = document.getElementsByName('red')[0].value;
    var green = document.getElementsByName('green')[0].value;
    var blue = document.getElementsByName('blue')[0].value;

    // create css rgb color value (e.g. rgb(255, 255, 255))
    var color = 'rgb(' + red + ', ' + green + ', ' + blue + ')';

    // set background color of body 
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

To make it work with background color of text area you need to change just last line. It could look like:

```
document.getElementById('id_of_my_textarea').style.backgroundColor = color;
```

Comment: Heres a jsfiddle too. Had just finished it when you posted the exact answer I had. https://jsfiddle.net/ke736x8o/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a JS fiddle of it working.
Uses

> `document.forms.RGB.elements`

and

> `document.forms.RGB.style.backgroundColor`

https://jsfiddle.net/xy12aten/

intentionally left the code wet so it's easier to read.

Comment: Forgot you wanted validation. Here is updated fiddle for that. Just wrap the part where you assign background color with conditional statement. if(redVal<256 && redVal>-1 && greenVal<256 && greenVal>-1 && blueVal<256 && blueVal>-1){...} https://jsfiddle.net/xy12aten/1/

Answer (score 0):

This should help get you going

**HTML**

```
<form name="RGB">
  <p>Red Value<input name="red" value="0" min="0" max="255" required   type="number"></p>
  <p>Green Value<input name="green" value="0" min="0" max="255" required type="number"></p>
  <p>Blue Value<input name="blue" value="0" min="0" max="255" required type="number"></p>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
var form = document.forms.RGB,
elem = form.elements;

form.onsubmit = function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  var red = elem.red.value,
      green = elem.green.value,
      blue = elem.blue.value;


  alert("The color = ("+red+","+green+","+blue+")");
  return true;
}
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/z3hzt8kf/